# Importing Intelij project to another

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have this problem, where i have InteliIJ project, where i want to have methods (such as generating random number, etc.). And i want to import it to another project, so i can call on that method, when im working on some project, but i dont know how.

I tried Import project from existing sources, where i chose that project, chose eclipse (because, when choosing i can choose Eclipse, gradle and maven and when im creating new project, build system has only IntelIJ, maven and gradle, so im choosing IntelIJ). Next step, i chose "Keep project...", but then i have nothing to select. So im wondering, do i still need to do something in that project, where i have these methods, or am i just dumb and doing it wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ IDEA projects are organized in modules. You can use a module in several projects. It should be possible to add the module with your "library methods" to your current project through "File" -> "Project Structure", "Project Settings" -> "Modules" (look for a "+" button on the top). Module files use the filename extension ".iml" and are typically located in the .idea directory in your project's root directory.

Instead of sharing your modules between projects, you can also create a new module in your current project (again through "File" -> "Project Structure", "Project Settings" -> "Modules") that points to the sources with your "library methods".